# How to use usernames instead of e-mail addresses for Dovecot login?

Tags: linux, dovecot, imap, postfix

I have a mail server set up on a Debian 7.2 machine running Dovecot 2.1.7 and Postfix 2.9.6. I have both Dovecot and Postfix set up to load virtual users from a database populated by Postfixadmin.

Currently the mailboxes are stored at `/var/mail/example.com/username` for each user for each domain, and Dovecot (IMAP) requires the full `username@example.com` to be given for authentication.

Would it be at all possible to add the ability to add alternative logins for certain e-mail addresses? Such as being able to login with `admin` instead of `admin@example.com`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Dovecot: Adding missing domain to login

Have you tried to use auth_default_realm configuration option to fill missing domain?

http://wiki2.dovecot.org/DomainLost

Comment: Most excellent! Any idea how I get Roundcube webmail to do the same thing? Now when I login with `username` to Roundcube I get the e-mail for `username@example.com` but the identity is `username@localhost`.

Comment: Got it! You need to set `$rcmail_config['username_domain'] = 'example.com';` to get Roundcube to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. I'm assuming that in this case, the mailbox will be at a different directory than for the domain users?

You would need to add that user to the userdatabase, and make sure that the MailLocation field points to the right place.

There's some more information about the userdatabase at [the dovecot wiki](http://wiki1.dovecot.org/UserDatabase).

Comment: Nope. It would just be a convenient shorthand login for certain domain users. It would still be associated with the domain mailbox.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution I found so far.

As @AnFi mentioned, you have to append or edit /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf file with

```
auth_default_realm = mydomain.com
```

Please refer this like for more information https://docs.iredmail.org/authenticate.without.domain.name.html